# Parsing a Character followed by a variable number of Integers in Boost Spirit

Tags: boost, boost-spirit

I am trying to parse a string of the form:

f 1 2 3 4
f 1 2 3
f 1 2 3 4 5

Using boost spirit, I have:

```
using boost::spirit::qi::uint_;
using boost::spirit::qi::double_;
using boost::spirit::qi::_1;
using boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse;
using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
using boost::phoenix::ref;
using boost::phoenix::push_back;

std::vector<unsigned int> v;

r = phrase_parse(first_, last_,

    //  Begin grammar
    (
        'f' >> uint_[push_back(ref(v), _1)] >>*(uint_[push_back(ref(v), _1)])
    )
    ,
    //  End grammar

    space);//  Begin grammar
```

However, I am getting a bunch of compile errors:

Error   C2064   term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
Error   C2668   'boost::phoenix::ref': ambiguous call to overloaded function
Error   C2780   'bool boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator &,Iterator,Expr &,const Skipper &,boost::spirit::qi::skip_flag)': expects 5 arguments - 3 provided

Not really sure whats wrong because the form just follows the example program given in the
boost spirit documentation.

Also, note that I am using boost 1_55 with MSVC 2015 ( can't really change these)

For a fixed number of integers after the 'f' the following compiles and works:

```
unsigned int v1 = 0, v2 = 0, v3 = 0;

r = phrase_parse(first_, last_,

     //  Begin grammar
     (
          'f' >> uint_[ref(v1) = _1]
      >> uint_[ref(v2) = _1] >> uint_[ref(v3) = _1]
     ),
    //  End grammar

   space);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't self contained, but we can guess that `ref` is ambgious, since `std::ref` will be picked due to `std::vector` being declared in namespace `std`: [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

(That problem doesn't occur with the separate `v1`, `v2`, `v3` since primitive types do not have an associated namespace).

Therefore being less liberal (more *hygienic*) with the using declarations this compiles fine for me on Boost 1.55.0:

**[Live On Coliru(c++11)](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11ccbd90b29f9631)**

```cpp
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/version.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

std::string values(std::vector<unsigned> const& v) {
    std::string r = "[";
    for (auto& el : v)
        r += (r.length() > 1 ? "," : "") + std::to_string(el);
    return r + "]";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Boost: " << BOOST_VERSION << " Spirit: " << std::hex << SPIRIT_VERSION << std::dec
              << std::endl;
    for (std::string const input :
         {"f ", "f1", "f", "f-3", "f1f2", "f 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5", "f 1 2 3 4 f 1 2 3 f 1 2 3 4 5"}) {
        std::vector<unsigned int>   v;
        std::string::const_iterator first_ = input.begin(), last_ = input.end();

        bool r = qi::phrase_parse( //
            first_, last_,
            ('f' >> qi::uint_[px::push_back(px::ref(v), qi::_1)] >>
             *(qi::uint_[px::push_back(px::ref(v), qi::_1)])),
            qi::space);

        std::cout << (r ? "OK" : "FAIL") << "\t"                      //
                  << input << " -> " << values(v)                     //
                  << " remain '" << std::string(first_, last_) << "'" //
                  << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Tested locally with Boost 1.55/Spirit v2.53:

[image]

### Side Notes: UNCOMPLICATE

However, there's no need for any of the complexity.

1. any sequence `p >> *p` is by definition equivalent to `+p`

   ```
   bool r = qi::phrase_parse(                                //
       first_, last_,                                        //
       'f' >> +qi::uint_[px::push_back(px::ref(v), qi::_1)], //
       qi::space);
   ```
2. push-back (back-insertion) is already the default action for container attributes, so [why have semantic actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)?

   ```
   bool r = qi::phrase_parse(first_, last_, 'f' >> +qi::uint_, qi::space, v);
   ```

   This has the exact same effect without the compilation overhead and code complexity. You'd never run into the ADL snag in the first place.

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be2c58492e4fc441)**¹

```cpp
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/version.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

std::string values(std::vector<unsigned> const& v) {
    std::string r = "[";
    for (auto& el : v)
        r += (r.length() > 1 ? "," : "") + std::to_string(el);
    return r + "]";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Boost: " << BOOST_VERSION << " Spirit: " << std::hex << SPIRIT_VERSION << std::dec
              << std::endl;
    for (std::string const input :
         {"f ", "f1", "f", "f-3", "f1f2", "f 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5", "f 1 2 3 4 f 1 2 3 f 1 2 3 4 5"}) {
        std::vector<unsigned int> v;
        auto f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
        bool r = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, 'f' >> +qi::uint_, qi::space, v);

        std::cout << (r ? "OK" : "FAIL") << "\t"             //
                  << input << " -> " << values(v)            //
                  << " remain '" << std::string(f, l) << "'" //
                  << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Printing the exact same output.

---

¹ note how the simplification also removed the dependance on now-deprecated Phoenix headers

Comment: Modernized https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da0f5ae6fd21ddc0, or using Spirit X3 (c++14/17): https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b1492cbd7bd186a

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Will try your suggestion and check mark as solved as soon as I have some spare time. By the way, any resources out there for boost spirit to get a good foundation on how it works?